# How to enable scrubber for tracks in itemType program

Tags: sonos

My application delivers tracks as programmed radio, using a container with itemType `program`. Users are allowed to use the scrubber to skip ahead within the track.

In the Sonos UI I can see the scrubber, but I cannot interact with it.

Is there any way to enable this behaviour?

[image: Example of non-functioning scrubber in Sonos UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When listening to a Program Radio Station some features are disabled. This includes the skip backwards function and the scrubber.  Unfortunately, There is currently no way to override this behavior and enable that functionality.